# Why is this function not returning the right number of common elements between the arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

I was solving an exercise which goes as follows:

> Create a function with the following prototype `int commons(int a[], int na, int b[], int nb)` which returns how many numbers the array **a** (of size `na`) has in common with array **b** (of size `nb`). The arrays are not ordered.

The exercise does not say what is supposed to happen when there is more than one number which is the same but for I want to suppose that if there is an array `a = { 1, 2, 2 }` and array `b = { 2, 0, 5}` they only have one element in common which is `2` (occurring once).

In order to solve this, I decided to loop through each number of the first array and check if it belong to the second, if it does, I'm gonna get the position and shift the second array in order to "remove" it from the array. However I had to make some adjustments, as once I shift it, the last item will be repeated so I chose to decrement the `len` variable. However I am getting unexpected results. The website which I'm testing at

```
int index_occur(int x, int a[], int N) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N && a[i] != x; i++); 
    return (i == N ? -1 : i);
}

int common(int a[], int na, int b[], int nb) { 
    int i, c = 0, j, index;
    int len = nb; 
    for (i = 0; i < na; i++) {
       if ((index = index_occur(a[i], b, len)) != -1) { 
            for (j = index; j < nb - 1; j++)
                b[j] = b[j + 1]; 
            len--; 
            c++;
        } 
    } 
    return c;
}
```

When I test on the website with the following arrays, here is what I get:

> Inputs: [ 1 12 13 14  5 16 17 18 19 110 111 12 113 114 115 116 117 18 119 12 ]
>
> [ 2  3  4  1 20 21 22 23  5 126 127 129 132 132 132 132 132 132 132 132 ]
>
> Output: expected `2` obtained `7`

I don't understand what is wrong with my code, for it not to produce the desired results.

Comment: This is weird, I get 2 when I run your code with the given input. Can you share the entire code including your main function?

Comment: Seems fine to me, maybe the problem is in the call, post rhe code where you call the function.

Comment: @chuck2002 I don't have a main function. I just write the function commons on this website and they run the tests and they are usually right. https://codeboard.io/projects/14846

Comment: Well maybe the problem is in the site. Write a simple main, and if the results you get are still wrong, then edit the question to show your main. If the results aren't still wrong - we can't fix the website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong in your testing code. I ran your functions with the posted arrays and I did get the expected output `2`.

Your code seems to work, but are some remarks:

- your inner loop should stop at `len - 1` instead of `nb - 1`.
- you modify the `b` array and effectively destroy its contents. You might want to move the found elements to the end so the array is just shuffled but still contains the same numbers.
- If you are going to modify the arrays, you might as well sort them and use a linear scan to count the elements in common.

Here is an alternative that does not modify the arrays:

```c
int count_occurrences(int x, const int a[], int n) {
    int count = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] == x)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int common(const int a[], int na, const int b[], int nb) {
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < na; i++) {
        int n = count_occurrences(a[i], b, nb);
        if (n > 0 && n > count_occurrences(a[i], a, i - 1))
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Your code does something different than mine.As I said in the description,  **if there is an array a = { 1, 2, 2 } and array b = { 2, 0, 5} they only have one element in common which is 2 (occurring once).** Your code would return 2 instead of 1.

Comment: @user13024289: The above code **does** return 1 for `a = {1,1,3}` ]and `b = {1,0,2}`. Duplicate elements in `a` are only counted if there are at least as many duplicates in `b`. The above code has the same quadratic complexity as yours.